How do we find the spin an equation “represents”?
It is very well known how the Klein-Gordon equation describes 0-spin particles (fields), Dirac’s 1/2-spin, Proca’s 1-spin…
But how do we know these functions describe particles with those spins? Given any quantum-relativistic equation we can discern what spin it represents? How?

There are two main approaches: either you calculate the eigenvalues of the spin operator in the second quantized theory or find the representation of $\mathfrak{spin}(3)$ acting on the field.

You might want to study: https://doi.org/10.2307/1968551
